# bootstrap collapsible panel not working inside the ng-if

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using a bootstrap collapsible panel with angular js. But when I put my collapsible panel inside the div and added `ng-if` collapsible not working.

```
User <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isUser"/>

<div class="col-md-12" ng-if="!isUser">
                 <div class="panel-group driving-license-settings" id="accordion">
                                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                                    <h4 class="panel-title"> </h4>
                                                    <div class="checkbox" id="testCheckBox">
                                                        <label data-target="#collapseOnes">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a"/> I have Driver License  
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseOnes" class="panel-collapse collapse in eh">
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <div class="driving-license-kind">
                                                         content
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
</div>
```

I am using below jquery  code for my collapsible area

```
    $('.collapse').collapse();
$("input[type='checkbox']").bind('click dblclick', function(evt) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parents('.panel-group').find('.collapse').slideDown('fast');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('.panel-group').find('.collapse').slideUp('fast');
    }
})
```

when I remove the 'ng-if' condition, collapsible panel working well. can u help me to solve this problem?
can not we user bootstrap collapsible panel inside the 'ng-if'.

Comment: When your `ng-if` condition is `false`, the element will be removed from DOM and you can't apply any operations on it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you the jquery call before your `collapsible panel` is rendered.

I believe `$(this).parents('.panel-group').find('.collapse')` will return nothing.

Remind you, `ng-if` does not render the DOM at all.

- The quick solution is to move to `ng-show`
- Another solution is to call jquery code when `isUser` will be false.

---

I suggest you do not mix angular js with jquery, bad practice.

You have bootstrap for angular js: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#collapse